# C# - error when applying numbering system to lists

Tags: c#, list, uniqueidentifier

I'm working on a program that builds and allows use of a  simulation of a chip-coin car park. To build the car park, I ask the user to input the name of the car park, the number of levels in the car park, and the number of parking spaces on each level.

There are several classes at work here:
`ParkingSpace` (represents a single space)
`ParkingSpaces` (collection class - public interface of a List)
`Level` (contains a `ParkingSpaces` instance as part of composition relationship)
`Levels` (collection class - public interface of a List)
`CarPark` (contains a 'Levels' instance as park of a composition relationship)

Basically, a car park contains a number of levels, and there are a number of spaces on each level.

This works fine so far, and they all construct properly (tested using output to inform how many levels and spaces created), but I have just tried to implement a numbering system (to give each space a unique ID) and run into a bit of a problem.

The carPark has an attribute `carParkID`, each `LevelID` has a `LevelID` and each `ParkingSpace` has a `SpaceID`. The `carParkID` should be assigned through user input when creating the carpark, and the rest should be worked out using a numbering algorithm.
Each level is given the ID `"carParkID-L(level#)"`, so that level 1 is `"carParkID-L1"`, level 2 is `"carParkID-L2"` etc. This works as expected.
However, the problem occurs when trying to assign names to the spaces on the level, because for some reason the spaces on every level then take the levelID of the highest level in the list, for example (assuming the carpark has 3 levels):

Level 2, Space 1 should have the spaceID `"carParkID-L2-0001"`, but ends up with the spaceID `"carParkID-L3-0001"`. This happens on every level, meaning that the first space on each level has the same ID instead of taking the actual level number into account.

The code that numbers the levels and spaces is shown below, I have stepped through it and everything but can't find the root of the problem. If you have any insight, please let me know!

```
    //apply numbering system to all levels in car park
    public void numberLevels(string carParkID)
    {
        //access all instances in collection
        for (int levelIndex = 0; levelIndex < Length(); levelIndex++)
        {
            //assign level at current index to variable
            Level l = At(levelIndex);
            //use formula to create level name
            string levID = carParkID + "-L" + Convert.ToString(levelIndex + 1);

            //apply created ID to level
            l.setLevelID(levID);

            for (int spaceIndex = 0; spaceIndex < l.getNumSpaces(); spaceIndex++)
            {
                //construct new space
                //hold state of instance at current index
                ParkingSpace ps = l.getSpacesOnLevel().At(spaceIndex);

                //const to set consistent ID
                //4 figures, any blanks default to 0
                //1 = 0001
                //123 = 0123
                //length of figure
                const int WIDTH = 4;
                //default number
                const char PADCHAR = '0';

                //extend formula to create space unique ID
                //include car park and level ID
                string psID = levID + "-" + Convert.ToString(spaceIndex + 1).PadLeft(WIDTH, PADCHAR);

                //apply numbering system to space
                ps.setSpaceID(psID);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you spot where I'm going wrong, or reply in the comments if you need any of the nested functions clarifying!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Could you please provide enough code for us to replicate your issue in a console app? Right now there are four compile errors in your code.

Comment: The code is split across several classes and a main method, do you have a preferred sharing space that I could upload it to and link you to? @Enigmativity

Comment: You should include it directly in your question. You should follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for providing code. You **shouldn't** link to external sites from SO.